# Regular expression starts with string and match all type of symbols, character, numbers

Tags: java, regex

I tried with

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Rejex {

    public static final String REGEX_CONSTANT="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9&\\-()$#@!^*=|'{}:.%_+?`~<>[]]*$"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(validateRegex(REGEX_CONSTANT,"dd[]"));
    }
    public static  boolean validateRegex(String regex, String value) 
    {
        Pattern patternObjects = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcherObject = patternObjects.matcher(value);
        return matcherObject.matches();
    }
}
```

It returns false, i want [] should be there in expression, i want expression starts with string and accepts all symbols, numbers,everything, with [], {}, () also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following regex :

```
"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9&\\-()$#@!^*=|'{}:.%_+?`~<>\\[\\]]*$"
```

[ and ] need to be escaped within your custom character class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: It's working fine, but it is not excepting  \  symbol.